# What are the names of these poker games

Tags: poker-history

My family and I play a poker and some of the games we play can't seem to found on the internet, there was no internet around when my dad learnt these because it was the 70's and in Ireland. The first one we play is 'four in the river' it's like Texas hold'em but with 4 cards dealt to each person instead of 2, 4 cards on the table instead of 5 and all turned one at a time.

The next one is called 'spade in the hole' everyone is dealt 5 cards 1 card at a time and one must be faced down at all time. You choose faced up or faced down for your next card. The pot is split between the person with the highest spade faced down and the best hand with all five cards (e.g. If you are dealt the ace of spades faced down and you keep it down then you know you'll win half.)

Comment: The second I know the term Black Mariah

Comment: First one has similarities (but not the same, so not answer) as Irish poker.   In Irish poker, you get dealt 4 cards, then after betting on the flop you discard 2 cards, then the rest of it is normal hold em.   Good variant for getting more playable hands.

Comment: I've always called split-with-high-spade "Chicago". Stud variants where the player chooses which of his cards is down are called "roll your own".

Answer (score 1):

The first one sounds like Omaha, but as noted, it is not.

After some research, I found these similar games:

[2-11](https://www.pagat.com/poker/variants/invented/shared.html#211)
[Buddy's Game](https://www.pagat.com/poker/variants/invented/shared.html#buddys)
[Odds and Ends](https://www.pagat.com/poker/variants/invented/shared.html#oddsandends)
[The game called 'The'](https://www.pagat.com/poker/variants/invented/shared.html#the)

And then, I found what appears to be the correct match, [Round the World](https://www.pagat.com/poker/variants/cincinnati.html#world), a variation of, or alternative name for [Cincinatti Poker](http://www.wikihow.com/Play-Cincinnati-Poker), depending on your source.

I've heard of the 2nd one, but I don't recall the name of it. But, as @Paparazzi mentions, the second may be Black Mariah, which is a variation of, or alternative name for [Chicago](https://www.pagat.com/poker/variants/chicago.html).

Comment: Thanks but Omaha has 5 community cards and you can only use 2 out of the 4 cards that you are dealt.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with Omaha, is just seemed similar. I've updated with what I believe are the correct names, as well as some other games similar to the first.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, really ive been searching for days and couldn't find anything